# Fetch TweetTimelineListAdapter's data

Tags: java, android, listview, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am newbie in java So I am sorry if I confuse you with my question.

My Problem is that I am getting a list of tweets through `TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter` and showing the data in `listview` like this

```
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
                .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                .build();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

All is working good, But What I want is to get(see) data inside `adapter`. I can only see the tweets in the `listview`. 
I need to put that adapter's data in an array for further use through `MainActivity`.

*Is there any way to do that or any Suggestions you can give Please share.*

Comment: `getItem(int position)` ?

Comment: can you give proper code as when I am going it on adaper, it shows errors. I mean what I should put in place of int position.

Comment: what errors? just call `adapter.getItem()` method

Comment: method getItem in class TimelineListAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
        found: no arguments

Comment: the full method signature is `android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int position)`, just pass `position` argument

Comment: sorry but I am unable to understand. Also I am using TweetTimelineListAdapter  adapter

Comment: what argument did you pass to `adapter.getItem()` method?

Comment: nothing. I don't even know what to pass, this is totally new to me

Comment: adapter has N items, so pass whatever from 0 to N - 1

Comment: when I pass 0 it crupt my app and this error shows up java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: so it is empty adapter: N is 0 (getCount() == 0)

Comment: System.out.println(adapter.getCount()==0) "true". Now what?

Comment: what is returning "true"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112989/discussion-between-atula-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in Android every adapter class provides you following methods:

```
public int getCount();
public T getItem(int position);
```

So you users can get all the data from the Adapter class as follows:

```
ArrayList<T> data= new ArrayList<T> ();
for(int i= 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    data.add(adapter.getItem(i));
}
```

So in your case:

This must be the code for TweetTimelineListAdapter taken from this [github url](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/TweetTimelineListAdapter.java)

```
package com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.TimelineDelegate;

/**
 * TweetTimelineListAdapter is a ListAdapter which can provide Timeline Tweets to ListViews.
 */
public class TweetTimelineListAdapter extends TimelineListAdapter<Tweet> {
    protected Callback<Tweet> actionCallback;
    final protected int styleResId;

    /**
     * Constructs a TweetTimelineListAdapter for the given Tweet Timeline.
     * @param context the context for row views.
     * @param timeline a Timeline&lt;Tweet&gt; providing access to Tweet data items.
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if timeline is null
     */
    public TweetTimelineListAdapter(Context context, Timeline<Tweet> timeline) {
        this(context, timeline, R.style.tw__TweetLightStyle, null);
    }

    TweetTimelineListAdapter(Context context, Timeline<Tweet> timeline, int styleResId,
            Callback<Tweet> cb) {
        this(context, new TimelineDelegate<>(timeline), styleResId, cb);
    }

    TweetTimelineListAdapter(Context context, TimelineDelegate<Tweet> delegate, int styleResId,
            Callback<Tweet> cb) {
        super(context, delegate);
        this.styleResId = styleResId;
        this.actionCallback = new ReplaceTweetCallback(delegate, cb);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a CompactTweetView by default. May be overridden to provide another view for the
     * Tweet item. If Tweet actions are enabled, be sure to call setOnActionCallback(actionCallback)
     * on each new subclass of BaseTweetView to ensure proper success and failure handling
     * for Tweet actions (favorite, unfavorite).
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        final Tweet tweet = getItem(position);
        if (rowView == null) {
            final BaseTweetView tv = new CompactTweetView(context, tweet, styleResId);
            tv.setOnActionCallback(actionCallback);
            rowView = tv;
        } else {
            ((BaseTweetView) rowView).setTweet(tweet);
        }
        return rowView;
    }

    /*
     * On success, sets the updated Tweet in the TimelineDelegate to replace any old copies
     * of the same Tweet by id.
     */
    static class ReplaceTweetCallback extends Callback<Tweet> {
        TimelineDelegate<Tweet> delegate;
        Callback<Tweet> cb;

        ReplaceTweetCallback(TimelineDelegate<Tweet> delegate, Callback<Tweet> cb) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
            this.cb = cb;
        }

        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            delegate.setItemById(result.data);
            if (cb != null) {
                cb.success(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            if (cb != null) {
                cb.failure(exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * TweetTimelineListAdapter Builder
     */
    public static class Builder {
        private Context context;
        private Timeline<Tweet> timeline;
        private Callback<Tweet> actionCallback;
        private int styleResId = R.style.tw__TweetLightStyle;

        /**
         * Constructs a Builder.
         * @param context Context for Tweet views.
         */
        public Builder(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the Tweet timeline data source.
         * @param timeline Timeline of Tweets
         */
        public Builder setTimeline(Timeline<Tweet> timeline) {
            this.timeline = timeline;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the Tweet view style by resource id.
         * @param styleResId resource id of the Tweet view style
         */
        public Builder setViewStyle(int styleResId) {
            this.styleResId = styleResId;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the callback to call when a Tweet action is performed on a Tweet view.
         * @param actionCallback called when a Tweet action is performed.
         */
        public Builder setOnActionCallback(Callback<Tweet> actionCallback) {
            this.actionCallback = actionCallback;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Builds a TweetTimelineListAdapter from Builder parameters.
         * @return a TweetTimelineListAdpater
         */
        public TweetTimelineListAdapter build() {
            return new TweetTimelineListAdapter(context, timeline, styleResId, actionCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

You are using it as below:

```
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
                .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                .build();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here `TweetTimelineListAdapter` extends `TimelineListAdapter`

and `TimelineListAdapter`extends `BaseAdapter`

And `BaseAdapter` class have following [methods](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/TimelineListAdapter.java):

```
public int getCount();
public T getItem(int position);
```

so you can get all the data from TweetTimelineListAdapter as follows:

```
ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet> ();
for(int i= 0; i<adapter.getCount();i++) {
    tweets.add(adapter.getItem(i));
}
```

Here you will have all the tweets from  `TweetTimelineListAdapter` in to your arraylist.

Comment: getting adapter.getCount() '0'. But I have tweets in listview.

Comment: so loop isn't calling up.

Comment: @Atula if that's the case than you need to extend TweetTimelineListAdapter in your app, and need to override the getCount() method to return valid count.

Comment: how i am supposed to do that?

Comment: @Atula you can create your own class something like this: AtulaTweetTimelineListAdapter extends TweetTimelineListAdapter, and than you can implement getCount() to return the count of timeline tweets.

Answer (score -1):

You should do so thing like this:

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();  
int count = adapter.getCount();  
for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {  
    tweets.add(adpater.getItem(i););  
}
```

I'm assuming that the objects returned by get item called Tweet (never used it).